# Android/Java best up to date mapper

Tags: java, mapper

In my Android app I need to perform some mappings between aplication layers. Mainly between DTOs and instances of domain classes.

So I've been looking for mappers, which could do my life easier, but most articles I have found are pretty old and they describes deprecated mappers oftentimes, like

- Dozer
- Nomin
- Transmorph
- Model Bridge

So far I found only 2 up to date mappers, such as

1. [mapStruct](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct)
2. [model mapper](https://github.com/jhalterman/modelmapper)

I'm confused which one to choose and is there a better mapper, which will fit my needs?

Basically I need mapper with simple and understandable API, whithout tonns of ugly code which I'll need to write to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in my project I use [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/).
It is simple to start. And it has nice documentation and broad functionality. Also, its advantage is in conventional mapping.

[Here](http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/) you will find plenty of examples using it.

**EDIT:**
As I can see, you provided link to GitHub repository of this project in the question.

Comment: so you use it for your Android projects, right? one more question, does ModelMapper can convert two fields into one, like in case with first name and family name?

Comment: @MikeHerasimov I used it a lot in server-side projects. Mostly when I was providing REST api. Well, you are able to add specific rules, it is extensible.

Comment: ok I'll take a look on it, the one think that I already like about it is that it doesn't use annotations, which IMHO messes code

Comment: OFFTOP it's the first time when my countryman answers to my question :D

Answer (score 1):

MapStruct is a great fit for Android apps (disclaimer: MapStruct project lead here) as it isn't a runtime library but a code generator that works at compile time.

I.e. you don't need to add any library to your app but will only add the generated mapper implementions. Resulting in a smaller app size and a great performance, too, as there is no reflection or runtime byte code generation involved, instead plain Java getter/setter calls. Which also makes mappings very easy to debug if needed.